# How can I take lines from a text file as an argument using a loop

Tags: bash, shell, loops, sh, getopts

If I have a text file called inventory.txt that looks like this:

```
america 
mexico 
england
```

If I run this code, it only runs through once for `america`

```
 while read line;
    do 
        while getopts "U:D:" opt;
        do
            case $opt in
                U)
                    SOURCE=$OPTARG
                    echo "SOURCE : $SOURCE"     
                    SITEID=$line
                    echo "SITE : $SITEID " >&2
                    ;;

                D)
                    DEST=$OPTARG
                    echo "DESTINATION : $DEST" >&2  
                    ;; 
            esac

        done

done < inventory.txt
```

How can I do this for all the lines in my text file?

Comment: Your outer loop runs through 3 iterations.  But the inner loop is only executed during the first one.

Comment: It seems really odd to run the `while getops` loop more than once, but if you really want to do this, you can just set OPTIND=1 at the top of the outer loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse the parameters first, then afterwards go through your file:

```
while getopts "U:D:" opt;
do
    case $opt in
        U)
            SOURCE=$OPTARG
            ;;

        D)
            DEST=$OPTARG
            ;; 
    esac
done


while read line;
do 
    echo "SOURCE : $SOURCE"     
    SITEID=$line
    echo "SITE : $SITEID " >&2
    echo "DESTINATION : $DEST" >&2  
done < inventory.txt
```